# In Java, is there something like "DoEvents" from VB6

Tags: java, vb6

I'm coming from VB6 and I'm new to Java. In VB6, `DoEvents` gives up the processor and allows it to process other threads. Is there a similar thing in Java? How do I use it?

Comment: The system "processes other threads" anyway.  You only have to yield if you're doing busywork on the event thread, which you shouldn't be doing in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> gives up the processor and allows it to process other threads.

[Thread#yield()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield%28%29) is the java counterpart to relinquish the control of the processors voluntarily.

From the javadoc for [java.lang.Thread#yield()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield%28%29):

> A hint to the scheduler that the current thread is willing to yield its current use of a processor. The scheduler is free to ignore this hint.
>   Yield is a heuristic attempt to improve relative progression between threads that would otherwise over-utilise a CPU. Its use should be combined with detailed profiling and benchmarking to ensure that it actually has the desired effect.
>
> It is rarely appropriate to use this method. It may be useful for debugging or testing purposes, where it may help to reproduce bugs due to race conditions. It may also be useful when designing concurrency control constructs such as the ones in the java.util.concurrent.locks package.

**Note**:
In case of Java based desktop UI frameworks like [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29), [RIM's UI application](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.1api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29), there are ways to modify the UI using `invokeLater()` type of semantics.

Comment: If that thread happens to be the event dispatch thread, yielding becomes useless.  You'd have to basically re-call into the message loop or something.  That's basically what `DoEvents` does, and what apps in Java, .net, etc shouldn't ever have to do.

Comment: @cHao, Agreed, due to availability of invokeLater() and invokeAndWait() semantics. Tried conveying the same in the response.

Answer (score 1):

Having moved from VB6 to Java myself and having searched for an answer to this very same question at the time, I can tell you that I had to change my way of thinking about how to do things. The need for "doEvents" is most likely due to you attempting to write a Java program in the same way you wrote VB6 or an attempt to port a VB6 project "line by line" to Java. Neither is a good idea. Take a good look at the swing tutorial (if this is about UI) and the threading tutorial whether it is UI or not. Pay a close attention to and try to understand how the Event Dispatch thread works. I found the Java tutorials to be a great starting place, they are now located at Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/   look at the samples and read the code, they are a good place to learn/experiment

You need to start thinking in Java and not translate VB6 to Java, it took me a while to get there but not too long and overcoming the need for "doEvents" will take you a long way down that path if you understand the way around it. Good luck, and welcome to Stackoverflow, this is a great place to look for help!